# Xamarin accuracy comparison

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, location

I'm creating localization application in Xamarin and I'm not sure, what localization accuracy should I use. I know about [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android), but I don't know how accurate is it in real life and how big are the time and other differences between this accuracies. My app will be something like let's say google maps and tracking frequency will be from 30 seconds up to many hours.

What are real differences betweet his accuracies and when to use which accuracy?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are real differences betweet his accuracies and when to use which accuracy?

Comment: The page you linked to clearly explains the difference in accuracy settings.  Which one to use is going to be dependent on your apps requirements.  Is 1000 m good enough for your app?  Or do you need something more precise?

Comment: Accuracy using like this:  `var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium);` **GeolocationAccuracy(.Lowest /.Low /.Medium /.High /.Best)**